# How to exclude code from an Android build flavor?

Tags: android

I have 2 build flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        ...
    }
    paid {
        ...
    }
}
```

AdMob is only included for the free flavor, like so:

```
dependencies {
    freeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'
    ...
}
```

This works fine when building the 'free' flavor, however, when building the 'paid' flavor the compiler is still trying to build the code in the 'free' source directory (even though it's unused) and because AdMob is not included as a 'paid' dependency it's causing the build to fail.

I tried:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        ...
    }
    paid {
        java {
            exclude ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can exclude all of the 'free' source files when building the 'paid' flavor?

And what's the point of having different code for different flavors if the compiler's going to try and build it all anyway?